# sql join function

Tags: sql, function, join

This is basically a database join question but it requires the use of a column-name to column-name mapping component that has me stumped.

I have multiple survey tables; for simplicity, let's say I have two, one from year 2010 (called 'd2010') and the other from 2011 (called 'd2011'). The rows correspond to surveys and the columns (which we can assume to be named 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', ... 'cN') correspond to responses to questions. So, 'd2010' looks like

```
         id  c1  c2  c3  .. cX
survey 1
survey 2
survey 3
...
survey N
```

while 'd2011' looks like

```
         id  c1  c2  c3  .. cY
survey 1
survey 2
survey 3
...
survey N
```

The primary goal is to show how the responses have changed from 2010 to 2011, for a particular question. Specifically, my goal is to create SQL commands that create new tables (with three columns) that shows, for a particular response, how the surveys differ between the two years:

```
         id  2010-response  2011-response
survey 1
survey 2
survey 3
...
survey N
```

If the column names had been kept consistent, then what I need would have been something as simple as

```
select d2011.id, d2010.c1 as 'last year', d2011.c1 'this year' from d2010 join d2011 on d2010.id=d2011.id;
```

Unfortunately, the folks who created the tables did not keep the column names consistent; for example,

```
c1 of 2010 corresponds to c2 of 2011
c2 of 2010 corresponds to c1 of 2011
c3 of 2010 corresponds to c3 of 2011
c4 of 2010 corresponds to c7 of 2011
...
```

So what I've been trying to do is to enter something like

```
select d2010.id, d2010.c1 as 'last year', d2011.f(c1) 'this year' from d2010 join d2011 on d2010.id=d2011.id;
```

where "d2011.f(c1)" indicates the use of a function that maps the column names of 2010 to those of 2011. The mapping is not simple enough to be expressed with a mathematical formula so I assume I need a table that goes something like

```
2010  2011
  c1    c2
  c2    c1
  c3    c3
  c4    c7
```

Is there a way to express in SQL the join operation I need? That is, with the map table, is there a way to convert the following into standard SQL (in general) and SQLite (in particular)?

```
select d2011.id, f(d2010.c1) as 'last year', d2011.c1 'this year' from d2010 join d2011 on d2010.id=d2011.id;.id;
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically looking for is a way to store column names in a table, and use those column names in a future query.  Unfortunately I believe you'll need to use Dynamic SQL. An example:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(1024)
set @SQL = 'select * from Table'
exec sp_executeSQL @SQL
```

So using your mapping table, it would be possible to return the 'mapped' column name and declare your join:

```
    declare @SQL nvarchar(1024)
    declare @mappedColumnName nvarchar(1024)

    select @mappedColumnName = 2011 from mappedTable where 2010 = 'c1'

    set @SQL = 'select *
    from d2010 join d2011 on d2010.id=' + @SQL + ';.id';

    exec sp_executeSQL @SQL
```

Another method I've recently used if available to you is the Entity Framework in .NET.  This allows you to use reflection to dynamically select column names within LINQ queries.

Both of these methods feel 'dirty' to me, but that's a reflection on whoever designed these these tables.  It may well be best to export them to Excel for the comparison instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not seem entirely clear . . . you can just do the join as:

```
select d2011.id, d2010.c2 as 'last year', d2011.c1 'this year'
from d2010 join d2011 on d2010.id = d2011.id
```

There is no way to specify a column dynamically in standard sql.  Dynamic SQL does give you this capability.

I suspect that what you want to do is most easily done by bringing the two table column lists into Excel, put them into two columns side-by-side, and build the SQL statement using Excel functions.